# Using custom error pages with ARR / Application Request Routing

Tags: iis, error-handling, custom-error-pages, arr

How can I display custom HTML instead of the following 502 response from ARR?

[image: 502 Server Error]

Traffic is directed to the server farm using a URL Rewrite rule on the server level.

Answer (score 0):

Open IIS and then on the server level, in the IIS section, click "Error codes". These files are global, which is the level you will want to change for your situation. There are also site level error pages. You can modify these files or you can point them to a different file that you have customized[IIS Error Pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6UDp.jpg).